# Adobe Animate AIR 30/32 Invalid Bitcast

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe-animate

I am getting Invalid Bitcast error when trying to compile with Adobe AIR SDK for app store.

What I've tried:

- Tried with SDK 30 and SDK 32 - same error
- Removed temporary files
- Removed all ANEs
- I tried removing all code and it worked
- I built a similar app and it worked
- Tried reinstalling Adobe Animate
- At some point it worked, I managed to create builds for Ad Hoc and App store distribution

I believe it could be something related either to code (but not sure why it worked before) or maybe it is something outside of the app files and code.

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you

**UPDATE**
After commenting and uncommenting the code to find out where is the error, it turns out that "row.bg.gotoAndStop(x)" is generating the error. No idea why. I commented these lines and now I can build

```
if (win == null) {
    //row.bg.gotoAndStop(1);
}
else if (win == true)
{
    //row.bg.gotoAndStop(2);
} 
else if (win == false) 
{
    //row.bg.gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Comment: I think it is related to https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2486666

Comment: I managed to find some more clues by commenting and uncommenting code to pinpoint the error line/s and I updated the question. Strange error though. Looks more like an Adobe Animate bug

Comment: Does it publish successfully without those lines? Looks weird though, I agree.

Comment: Yes, it works without these lines. I managed to build it and upload it to store. Also, it works just fine in the simulator, with these lines. The games were created like 3 years ago and now I updated them. Who knows what might happen in these years in the Adobe AIR SDKs

Comment: Just work around then, I guess? Create new instances of the graphics you want there, rather than navigate the **bg**'s timeline?